# PHP - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Contentful\Delivery\Client' not found

Tags: php, class, sdk, composer-php, contentful

I'm getting the following error when I try to get started with the Contentful PHP SDK.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Contentful\Delivery\Client' not found in /home/rpard/app/process-email-alerts.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /home/rpard/public_html/reach.php(2): require() #1 {main} thrown in /home/rpard/app/process-email-alerts.php on line 16
```

I'm using the exact snippet (except with credentials) they show on their [docs page](https://github.com/contentful/contentful.php#getting-started):

```
$client = new \Contentful\Delivery\Client(
    '*********',
    '*********'
);
```

The SDK was installed via Composer via the following:

```
composer require contentful/contentful
```

I've never used Composer before today so perhaps I'm missing something that will be obvious to someone. Thank you.

Comment: If this is your first time with composer, check out how to load it. Are you using something like this in your code? `require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: I'm using literally what I put above. The snippet from the docs doesn't say to do anything else, like require'ing in files. That did look an obvious omission to me, but like I say, first time, so I thought perhaps Composer did something magic and all I needed was the instantiation line.

Comment: Docs: https://github.com/contentful/contentful.php#getting-started

Comment: OK it seems I needed exactly what you put. If you put that as an answer I'll accept it. Told you it would be simple for someone who knew! Not sure why the Contentful docs don't make that step explicit. Thanks.